# Can I use service worker with socket-io?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to push notification to desktop and mobile. For that I following this article: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en

I have two question:

1. Can I use push notification to send notification after all tabs are closed (Chrome restart?)
2. Can I trigger the notification by using `socket.io` for example `io.on('message')` instead of `GCM`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two questions, Two answers:

---

> **Can I use push notification to send notification after all tabs are closed (Chrome restart?)**

Yes. The notification can be sent for Desktop Chrome, and Android Chrome, after chrome is closed. using Notification API.

---

> **Can I trigger the notification by using socket.io for example io.on('message') instead of GCM?**

No. The service worker is not working in the background, while the browser / tabs are closed. The only way to wake up the service worker is by using GCM.